# Send an Email with a list of Leads without using Apex

Tags: email, email-template, email-alert

I'm developing a Visualforce page which Users will use to check for duplicate Leads.  The VF page will do a SOSL lookup on certain fields, returning Leads that match and display those in a table.

I want the Users to be able to select one or more duplicate Leads and then click a button which will send an Email with links to the Lead and all potential duplicates.

Is this possible to do without Apex?  Ideally I'd like to pass use the base Lead record and a list of the potential duplicate Lead records.

Comment: What are the other possible ways you want to overcome?

Comment: @SantanuBoral  I know I can do this in Apex, building up my email body as a String.  I was hoping that I could maybe created an Email Template or Email Alert or maybe use Flow to handle this, but in all my searching I haven't seen anything that would allow me to pass in a List variable to use for the potential duplicate Leads.

Comment: @DougB I can think of at probably five different ways you could theoretically send the email itself without Apex Code directly building the text. Do you have a preferred configuration method you'd like to try it in, if it could be done?

Comment: @sfdcfox My preference is always for declarative features, and simplicity.

Comment: @DougB I understand, but this question is tipping towards being closed. Just choose which declarative feature you'd like to use, I'll give you a declarative answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox Email Templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Visualforce Email Template can do this, but you'd have to create some intermediate data. I'd probably suggest two custom objects: one for the primary lead, the other for the selected leads. You could even wrap this up into a process builder/flow/workflow scenario. Insert the parent record, insert the children records, then update a checkbox on the parent to trigger the email.

You might use this as a base:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Selected Duplicate Leads" recipientType="User" relatedToType="MasterLead__c">
    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
I&apos;ve identified some possibly duplicate leads for {!relatedTo.Lead__r.Name}. Could you look at these?
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.SelectedLeads__r}" var="selectedLead">
{!selectedLead.Lead__r.Name} / {!selectedLead.Lead__c}
</apex:repeat>
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Of course, you can make it in HTML, too, create links, or whatever else you'd like to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but creating two new objects in Salesforce just to handle this functionality is a little overkill at the moment.  I'm going to accept your answer as it accomplishes what I wanted to do.  However I will stick to using Apex to create the email body.